# How can I wait end to work async callback HttpWebRequest on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, compact-framework

Sorry, it's questions already was on stackoverflow, but I don't found answer. Maybe it's classic, but I can't understand, how to solve this problem :( 
I have Singletone class for working with web service:

```
public sealed class GYAccessService
    {
        static GYAccessService instance = null;
        static readonly object padlock = new object();
        public string Atoken { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Uid { get; set; }
        const string UrlRequest = "http://site.html";

    private GYAccessService()
    {

    }

    public static GYAccessService Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new GYAccessService();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }


    public void sendPost(string postData)
    {
        PostData = "request=" + postData;
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UrlRequest);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        // Start the request
        webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(getRequestStreamCallback), webRequest);

    }

    private void getRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        // End the stream request operation
        Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PostData);

        // Add the post data to the web request
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        // Start the web request
        webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(getResponseCallback), webRequest);
    }

    private void getResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response;

            // End the get response operation
            response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
            var Response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            streamResponse.Close();
            streamReader.Close();
            response.Close();
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Response)))
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ServiceResponse));
                ServiceResponse res = (ServiceResponse)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
                // I want to return res  in main thread
            }

        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            // Error treatment                
           ServiceResponse err = new ServiceResponse();
           err.Message = e.Message;
        }
    }

    public string getRequestString(string model, string method, Params parametrs, string auth = null)
    {
        Function func = new Function();
        func.Model = model;
        func.Method = method;
        func.Params = parametrs;
        ServiceRequest req = new ServiceRequest() { Function = func };
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req);
        ServiceResponse deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceResponse>(json);
        return json;
    }
}
```

I have call sendPost() in main thread, I want to return response in this function.

```
 GYAccessService gy = GYAccessService.Instance;
 gy.sendPost(postData); 
 //I want to use the response here
```

But in WP 7 HttpWebRequest has not GetResponse, only BeginGetResponse. I use callback and don't know how can I return response from callback. I put up with it, I can set property response my Singletone and get it after end async callback, but I don't know how can I block async callback. It's really problem, I try to use WaitOne()/Set() - don't help me, my app just frozen. I try to use IAsyncResult handle, but not success. How can I wait end to work async callback? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `EndGetResponse` method and process the result in it. It is asynchronous, so you will not be able to immediately get the result after you call `gy.sendPost(postData);`, you have to use it as a call back.

If I may suggest, there is a simpler way for such HTTP calls, use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). It is a great and easy to use library that also works with Windows Phone.

Comment: thank to the help! I don't try this code now, but I checked link RestSharp. In example synchronized and asynchronous request, it will be working on Windows Phone 7? I mean sync request?

Comment: @Alexandr no, you cannot make synch requests in windows phone, you have to always use async